# How to retrive data from OneToOne Relational Model in DRF using API view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have imported `User` model and customized it a/c to my need and make OneToOne Relation with `UserProfileModel` Model. While retrieving data I got this error.
"The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `AnonymousUser` instance.
Original exception text was: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'gender'."

My Model is :

```
class UserProfileModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='userprofilemodel')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    locality = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    pin = models.IntegerField()
    state = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    profile_image = models.FileField(upload_to='user_profile_image', blank=True)
```

My Serializer looks like:

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
class Meta: 
    model= User 
    fields = ['id', 'name' , 'email','mobile',]

class UserProfileModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta: 
        model= UserProfileModel 
        fields = ['user','gender' , 'locality','city','address','pin','state','profile_image', ]
```

My view looks like:
class UserProfileDataView(APIView):

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
    # user = UserProfileModel.objects.all()
    serializer = UserProfileModelSerializer(request.user)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I want to retrieve profile data of the logged user using UserProfileModel Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue in that you are passing a `User` instance to the `UserProfileModelSerializer`, which is expecting a `UserProfileModel` instance. To fix this you need to change:

```
serializer = UserProfileModelSerializer(request.user)
```

to

```
serializer = UserProfileModelSerializer(request.user.userprofilemodel)
```

where `userprofilemodel` is the `related_name` you have set on the `user` field in your `UserProfileModel`.

Second issue is, as Mohamed Beltagy said, you're allowing anyone to access the view, including unauthenticated users. Django rest framework has a built in mixin that you can use to restrict access to authenticated users only (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticated).

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


class UserProfileDataView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is you are passing an anonymous user which has no profile ( you permit non-authenticated users access this view)

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
    # user = UserProfileModel.objects.all()
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        serializer = UserProfileModelSerializer(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```